# Angularjs - Dynamically change dom with directives or widgets?

Tags: jquery, widget, angularjs, using-directives

my goal is to understand how to use angularJS correctly. I want to be able to tie a selection of variable to dynamically changing the DOM structure using angularJS. I dont think I'm quite understanding the documentation that angular provides and I haven't found any examples here or otherwise. Any help is appreciated.

The idea is that I have this use case where I first start with the selection of the type and from that type selected, the appropriate input type elements will be created and then recorded later with the ng-model (from textareas to checkboxes for example), all the while controlled by the angularjs controller for validation/restrictions. I'm used to the idea of having clone-able elements on the page and destroying and creating new with jQuery, but I've been reading that controllers should not have this logic and should instead be created with directives/widgets. I dont see any examples of directives or widgets being manipulated in this way however so I'm not even sure how to proceed. Can I use directives to manipulate the DOM in this way, not just once but multiple times based on a watched element?

Example of what I would like to do.

```
$scope.types = ['Type1','Type2']

// something along the lines of...
$scope.layouts = {'Type1':['textarea','textarea'], 'Type2':['numeric','datepicker']}
```

Select Type 1:

- Show 2 text areas

Select Type 2:

- Show a numeric input
- Show a date picker

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is how I would do it. Note that this is a just a starting point. There is still a matter of binding to particular values in the corresponding inputs. I hope it helps.

Markup:

```
<html ng-app="App" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

<body>

  <component index="0"></component>
  <component index="1"></component>
  Current type: {{type}}
  <button ng-click="toggleType()">Toggle</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Directive:

```
var ngApp = angular.module('App', []).directive('component', function() {
  var link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var render = function() {
      var t = scope.layouts[scope.type][attrs.index];
      if (t === 'textarea') {
        element.html('<' + t + ' /><br>');
      }
      else {
        element.html('<input type="' + t + '"><br>');
      }
    };
    //key point here to watch for changes of the type property
    scope.$watch('type', function(newValue, oldValue) {
      render();
    });

    render();
  };
  return {
    restrict : 'E',
    link : link
  }
});
```

Controller:

```
var MainCtrl = function MainCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.type = 'Type1';
  $scope.types = [ 'Type1', 'Type2' ];
  $scope.layouts = {
    'Type1' : [ 'textarea', 'textarea' ],
    'Type2' : [ 'number', 'text' ]
  };

  $scope.toggleType = function() {
    if ($scope.type === 'Type1') {
      $scope.type = 'Type2';
    }
    else {
      $scope.type = 'Type1';
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: This is where I was going, I wish either there were more examples that I could learn from their site. That watch function is very handy for this.

This is exactly the type of thing I was looking for. I appreciate the help!

Comment: (concerning directive code:) I think you shouldn't add a `scope.$watch` inside `render`, as you need to setup the `$watch` only once.

Comment: @m01 it's actually in the link function. Is it actually running more than once?

Comment: @Liviu nice answer,  but how to bind particular values in the corresponding inputs

Comment: @Deep3015 I'd suggest you ask a separate question with some examples of what you are struggling with.

Comment: @Liviu I am able to bind values. How to toggle on ngrepeat [Sample ] (http://stackoverflow.com/q/41641897/3898339)

Answer (score 4):

The most drop dead easy way I can think of doing this is by just using ng-show and ng-hide.

http://jsfiddle.net/cfchase/Xn7PA/

```
<select ng-model="selected_type" ng-options="t for t in types">
</select>

<div ng-show="selected_type=='Type1'">
    <input type="text" id="text1" ng-model="text1"/>
    <input type="text" id="text2" ng-model="text2"/>
</div>

<div ng-show="selected_type=='Type2'">
    <input type="number" id="numeric1" ng-model="numeric1"/>
    <input type="date" id="date1" ng-model="date1"/>
</div>
```

Of course you could clean this up without putting any logic in the html, but I didn't want to cloud the issue with extra stuff in the controller.

For validation, refer to the [forms documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).  It's likely you will use mostly the AngularJS built in validation with some custom ones you build.

As for directives, the [online docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) are dense, but it will click after you've experimented for awhile.  For a gentler introduction, Jon Lindquist has a hello world tutorial on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yg-R1gchccg).  Directives are definitely the way to do DOM manipulation in Angular.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this and it seems to work, but leaves me unable to easily make changes to the element once I have more. That video sure helped!